# Post request for adding new data got TypeError: Cannot read property 'discountValue' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I got two object class below. I try to add new device but got type error "cannot read property 'discountValue' of undefined.

```js
export class Device {
  id: number;
  siteId: number;
  ValidationDetail: ValidationDetailVM;
}
export class ValidationDetailVM {
  id: number;
  
  discountValue: number;

}
 onNewDeviceAddFormSubmitted(value: AccessDeviceModels.Device): void {const newDevice = new AccessDeviceModels.Device();

    newDevice.siteId = +value.siteId;
    
    newDevice.ValidationDetail.discountValue = +value.ValidationDetail.discountValue;


}
```

Comment: after the assignment of siteId you need to set ValidationDetail to a new object like that: newDevice.ValidationDetail = {}. Then you can simply do newDevice.ValidationDetail['discountValue'] = whatever_you_please.

Comment: So, after newDevice.iste=+value.siteId;  newDevice.ValidationDetails= {what should i add here}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValidationDetail` property is not initialized with any value in the your `Device` Object Class. Therefore you are getting an error for trying to access `newDevice.ValidationDetail.discountValue` as there isnt any value assigned to `newDevice.ValidationDetail`, and `ValidationDetail` will be taken to be undefined.

There are a few ways to resolve this.

1. Initialize a default value for your new `ValidationDetail` within your `Device` Object class
2. Construct the ValidationDetail instance as part of your device's constructor. This ensures that there will always be a valid value